I am trying to use multiple threads using ib_insync but as soon as I try to fetch data inside any thread I get 'no current event in loop'
I am trying to fetch options data in multiple threads using ib_insync, I am able to fetch data in main thread but as soon as I enter into another thread it starts giving me
'RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (thread_9_call)'
def thread_9_call(sp,s,date,stoploss,target,hedge_sp,contract_k,hedge_contract_k):
    global call_9
    contract = Option('SPX', date, sp, s,multiplier=100, exchange='SMART', currency='USD')
    base_time = (dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=60)).time()
    
    hedge = Option('SPX', date, hedge_sp, s,multiplier=100, exchange='SMART', currency='USD')
    loop = None
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ticker = ib.reqTickers(contract)[0]
    target_time = dt.time(15, 17)  # 15:17 (3:17 PM)
    print("Thread 1 active")
    print("Stoploss: ",end="")
    print(stoploss)
    print("Target: ",end="")
    print(call_9)
    print(target)
    while(True):
        
        contract = Option('SPX', date, sp, s,multiplier=100, exchange='SMART', currency='USD')
        ticker = ib.reqTickers(contract)[0]
        current_price = ticker.marketPrice()

I am getting error in
current_price = ticker.marketPrice()

I tried to start new asyncio loop inside the thread, but was unable to figure out proper way to do that, or it didn't work.
Can someone please help me in this regard?

It doesn't make any sense to call asyncio.get_event_loop if you're not in an async function. The way you start an async event loop is by using asyncio.run() to run an async function.
